# How to increment an integer and save it for future use without database

Tags: php, int, increment

I want to take an integer from a webpage, increment it when a form is submitted, and then replace the old int with the new one in the same place on the webpage. The updated int should be visible for all users and not just a single computer. I am using PHP and just cannot seem to accomplish this easy-seeming task.

Also using databases is not possible since I am having issues with connecting to my database at the moment.

This is the code that I have, it is for a type of silent auction that I am creating for my grad class.

```
<?php
$nameB = $priceB = $numbB = $emailB = false;

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if(empty($_POST['name']))
        {$nameERR = "Name is required"; $nameB = true;}
    if(empty($_POST['price']))
        {$priceERR = "A bet amount is required"; $priceB = true;}
    if(empty($_POST['number']))
        {$numERR = "A bet amount is required"; $numbB = true;}
    if(empty($_POST['email']))
        {$emailERR = "A bet amount is required"; $emailB = true;}
}

if($_POST && $nameB == false && $priceB == false && $numbB == false && $emailB == false) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $numb = $_POST['number'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $betAmount = $_POST['price'];
}

$filename = 'counter.txt';
if(!file_exists($filename)) {
    $bids = 0;
}
else
    $bids = file_get_contents ($filename);
$bids++;
file_put_contents($filename, $bids);

function getBids() {
    if(!file_exists($filename)) {
        $bids = 0;
    }
    else
        $bids = file_get_contents ($filename);
}
?>

<html>
<body>
<form>
</form>
Number of Bids:
<br>
<?php echo getBids(); ?>
</html>
```

The form actually has content on it but it does not relate to the question. The only thing that is relevant is the submit button which sends out a confirmation email. When that is pressed the counter should increase by one.

I hope I explained this well enough.

Comment: Without a database you would need to save ur int to a file, then on reload of the page, add 1 to the int and save it back to the file. Honestly fix ur db issue, will make life alot easier.

Comment: $int++;
echo $int;
managing variable state is up to you

Answer (score 1):

try it in this way

```
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['SOME_THING'])) {
   if ( isset($_SESSION['int']) ) {
      $_SESSION['int'] = $_SESSION['int']+1;
   } else {
      $_SESSION['int'] = 1;
   }
}
```

add this code where your form posts

Comment: I think user want to save the value for the other visitors too, session only hold it for a single visitor .

Comment: I clarified the question to state that I wanted to set the value for other users as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a file for storing the counter, like this :

```
//after form submit
$filename='counter.txt';
if(!file_exists($filename)){
    $counter = 0 ;
}
else
    $counter = file_get_contents ($filename);
$counter++;
file_put_contents($filename, $counter); //save the new counter ( +1 )
```

and every other time that you want to use the number in any place, get it just like this :

```
if(!file_exists($filename)){
        $counter = 0 ;
    }
else
        $counter = file_get_contents ($filename);
```

**Update :** your  `getBids()` function must return a value  like this :

```
function getBids() {
    $filename='counter.txt'; // ADD THIS LINE
    if(!file_exists($filename)) {
        $bids = 0;
    }
    else
        $bids = file_get_contents ($filename);
    return $bids; //ADD THIS LINE
}
```

Comment: I updated the question so that you could use it to show where to place the snippets of code you posted. I tried it out how you said and nothing happened.

Comment: This is still not working, the number does not update on the page, and the number in the text file increases every time I refresh the page, not every time I submit the form.

Comment: **note** : you did not define the `$filename`, look at the update again, look for `ADD THIS LINE`

Comment: Alright, now I have another function called addBids() and I was going to put that into an onsubmit function in the form. But the counter keeps increasing every time I refresh the page, without actually submitting the form.

Comment: do this `if($_POST){ addBids(); }`

Answer (score 0):

Please manage first your connection with your database in order to successfully answer you question. If you're already connected to your database, then add this codes:

```
<?php
$conn; // connection link to your database
$query = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT max(int) as int FROM tbl_table") or die("Error" . mysqli_error());
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
$result = $row['int'] + 1;
echo $result;
?>
```

Hopes this helps.

Comment: the question is about ' not to use database ' in doing that .